# How do I control a job's "name" in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to control the titles of my xterm windows and my cleverness has finally outpaced my knowledge.  :-)

I have three functions: one which sets the title of the window; one which takes a passed command, calls the title function, and executes the command; and one which resumes a job after using `jobs` to determine the title:

```
title () {
    echo -en "\e]1;$(hostname) : $1\a\e]2;$(hostname) : $2\a"
}

run () {
    title $(basename $1) "$*";
    $*
}

fg () {
    if [[ "x" == "x$1" ]]; then
        title $(jobs | awk '/\['$1'\]/{print $3}') "$(jobs | awk -F '  +' '/\[[0-9]\]\+/{print $3}')";
    else
        title $(jobs | awk '/\['$1'\]/{print $3}') "$(jobs | awk -F '  +' '/\['$1'\]/{print $3}')";
    fi;
    builtin fg $*
}
```

Now, all of this is working beautifully… well, mostly.  Setting the title by calling the function manually works fine.  Setting the title by way of the `run` function works fine.  Setting the title by resuming a job works fine… unless the job was started with the `run` function:

```
$ nano foo.txt
<CTRL-Z>
$ run nano bar.txt
<CTRL-Z>
$ jobs
[1]-  Stopped                 nano foo.txt
[2]+  Stopped                 $*
```

Well, I suppose that *is*, technically, the name of the command being executed by the `run` function, but that isn't really a useful thing to know, in this case.

So, since I have not only reached but *far exceeded* the limits of my knowledge about Bash, perhaps someone here can help me fix this.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it isn't ideal, but I've come up with a solution which at least sets my titles correctly:

```
fg () {
    if [[ "x" == "x$1" ]]; then
        _CMD=$(ps -o cmd --no-headers $(jobs -l | awk '/\[[0-9]\]\+/{print $2}'));
    else
        _CMD=$(ps -o cmd --no-headers $(jobs -l | awk '/\['$1'\]/{print $2}'));
    fi;
    title $(basename $(echo $_CMD | awk '{print $1}')) "$_CMD";
    unset _CMD;
    builtin fg $*;
}
```

This uses `jobs`' -l option to get the process ID, then finds it with `ps`, which has the correct command listed.  Unfortunately, `ps` seems to be quite slow, causing a noticeable delay (~¼ second) when resuming.

Answer (score 0):

man bash says:

> `fg [jobspec]`
>       Resume jobspec in the foreground, and make it the  current  job.
>       If jobspec is not present, the shell’s notion of the current job
>       is used.

And on the 'current job':

> The symbols  `%%`  and
>       `%+`  refer  to  the shell’s notion of the current job, which is the last
>       job stopped while it was in the foreground  or  started  in  the  background.

This is what you really want to do; emulate what the fg command is doing anyway.

Most of the other tricks here are detailed in Parameter Expansion.

```
myfg() { # just so I know what I'm invoking while testing
    local cmdline
    cmdline=$(jobs -l "${1:-%%}") || return # bail if jobs failed
    cmdline=${cmdline:30} # Extract the part we want
    title "${cmdline%% *}" "${cmdline}"

    builtin fg "$jobspec"
}
```

For your run command, in many cases, the eval command will do what you
want:

```
eval "$@"
```

But it'd be nice to armor each word with single quotes to prevent
reevaluating it:

```
eval_safe() {
    local args
    args=( )
    for word in "$@"; do
        word=\'${word//\'/"'\\''"}\'
        args+=( "$word" )
    done
    eval "${args[*]}"
}
```

Quoting is where bash's syntax becomes *really* confusing. I'm not quoting `word=${...}` whereas I am quoting it in the array. Whether you're quoted or not matters *inside* the substitution syntax. And in a single assignment, bash does no word splitting, whereas it does in the array. (It's possible to do `"${array[@]//source/target}"`
and do it in one shot, but we're dealing with multiple levels of
quoting already.)

Anyway, this will evaluate the words and pass them back to bash, quoted if
there are wierd characters in them.

That's adding a bunch of ugly quotes where they're probably not
necessary, so let's add:

```
[[ $word =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_./]+$ ]] || word=${...}
```

This says, "the word matches this safe regex, or we quote it." This is at least reasonably standard regex syntax, except that unlike every other language, you generally don't delimit the regex.

Comment: `$*` is wrong but so is `eval "$@"`. The proper way is simply `"$@"`. There's also no need to have functions like `eval_safe()`. `eval_safe()` may also double-protect an already-quoted argument set.

Comment: No, try this: `foo() { "$@" & }; foo sleep 100; jobs -l` and you'll see why.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. Good luck with `eval_safe()` for a quick look shows that's it not enough yet for quoting arguments with eval.